# trouble with launching an activity with ListView from another activity

Tags: android

**I have a strange problem (for me) when i launch an activity and this activity has a listview from another activity it didn't work but when i send a string to fill the listview it launches !! 
here is the activity from where i will launch the another activity 
(the problem is in the second intent which will go to show.class )

```
package com.hema.colornotes;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b1,b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btAdd);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btShow);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,add.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, show.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }




}
```

and here is the activity i need to launch

```
package com.hema.colornotes;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class show extends ActionBarActivity {
    Context context;
    List<String> tasks;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

        context = this;
        tasks = new ArrayList<String>();


        // second parameter is row layout,
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tasks);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getExtras().getString("message");

        tasks.add(value);

        // this method will refresh your listview manually
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }


}
```

and that's the activity which worked well and launched the show activity because i sent a string

```
package com.hema.colornotes;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class add extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText note;

    Button b1,b2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btSave);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btCancel);


        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNote);
                String notes = note.getText().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(add.this, show.class);
                i.putExtra("message", notes);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(add.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }


}
```

thanks in advance !**

Comment: its recommended to start a class name with capital letter.. but it not affect your functionality

Comment: so should i delete all the classes and rename them with capital letter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you dont send bundle to show activity, It would have crashed the app with null pointer exception.  That is why, it did not work.
When you send the bundle, show activity gets the required data to display. So it works fine!

Comment: You have to pass the "message" value in the bundle! Only then show activity will run. If you are not passing the value, then it will lead to crash.

Comment: I passed it in bundle but when i click on the button bt2 in mainactivity it doesn't show me the third activity yet !

Answer (score 0):

Your second activity is set to get "message" from intent so when you don't put any string it the first intent your second activity will crash.

Comment: sorry but i didn't get what should I modify in the code ?